# wordpress: comments reroute to old domain

Tags: wordpress, url, dns, comments, transfer

I'm stumped on this one and am getting no help from the guys at wordpress.org.

**Site concerning:** wallabiesgold.com

**The issue:** Comments are not showing in the dashboard or the site. they are infact redirecting to a previous domain.

**How I broke this:** Ok. The site was from wordpress.com. I used 'duplicator' to move it to a private host. I rebuilt the site on flavology.com. I then migrated the site to wallabiesgold.com (on the same server).

Everything appears to be in order except new blog comments, You are more than welcome to make a comment and see what happens. Although I have deleted wordpress from flavology.com I know for a fact that the new comments were appearing over there for 'approval'.

I have run 'search and replace' plugin to try and replace urls. I have also used phpMyAdmin in an attempt to search and replace the url's in the database. I have also since deleted the database that was used by flavology.com so the comments are now simply being sent to a site that doesnt exist.

My synopsis is that 'somewhere' there is a leftover url that points the comments to flavology.com. I just don't know where that would be. I don't believe it points directly to the (now deleted) old database as when you attempt to comment you will see flavology.com appear in a box under the post.

Answer (score -1):

Ah infact managed to resolve the issue myself, it was to do with jetpack, I had to remove the connection and re-add it :)

Thanks